# Javascript - why my function is recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback

I don't know where am I going wrong. Why is my function resursive? I expect a result of sum = 3;

```
function init() {
  let object = {
    firsNum: 1,
    sum: 0,
  };
  add(1, object.firsNum, fun);
  console.log(object.sum);
}

function fun(a) {
  a.firstNum++;
  a.sum += a.firsNum;
  fun(a);
}

function add(a, b, callback) {
  return callback(a + b);
}
init();
```

Comment: What do you mean *why* is it recursive? It's recursive *because it calls itself*.

Comment: You call `fun` in `fun`

Comment: make sense you are calling function `fun` inside `fun`

Comment: also the `a.firstName` and `a.sum` will be undefined you are passing three args not an object

Comment: fun(a); is making recursive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't fully understand every programming concept you've used in your code.

Apart from that your original code contains a typo: `a.firstNum++;` where it should read `firsNum` like in all other places.

Let's break down your code into separate concerns.

## Recursion

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_programs) means that a function calls itself. Recursion is one way to compute, iterate or traverse data. The other one is iteration using loops like `while` or `for`.

Let's look at this simplified example:

```
function recurse(counter) {
   console.log(counter);
   recurse(counter + 1);
}
recurse(0);
```

This will call `recurse()` indefinitely since there's nothing that stops it to call itself. Recursion as well as iteration require some stop condition to break the recursion.

If you'd like to stop at a certain value you'd have to call the function only until that condition is met:

```
function recurse(counter) {
   console.log(counter);
   if (counter < 42) {
      recurse(counter + 1);
   }
}
recurse(0);
```

This will only recurse and increment until 42 is reached.

You could even pass the stop condition with the function itself:

```
function recurse(counter, maxValue) {
   console.log(counter);
   if (counter < maxValue) {
      recurse(counter + 1, maxValue); // maxValue gets passed along
   }
}
recurse(0, 42);
```

To make your recursive function stop at a certain value you've to add such a condition:

```
function fun(a) {
  a.firstNum++;
  a.sum += a.firstNum;
  if (a.sum < a.maxNum) {
    fun(a);
  }
}
```

You'd then have to ensure your object specifies the condition:

```
let object = {
  maxNum: 3, // stop condition added
  firsNum: 1,
  sum: 0,
};
```

Though this on its own won't solve the problem. Read on.

## Callbacks

Callbacks are functions passed as function parameters, object properties or array elements to other functions.

Callbacks allow you to decide what function to call during the runtime without having to implement branching behavior using `if` or `switch` statements and requiring certain function names at time of writing.

```
function someCallback() { /* ... */ }

function callTheCallback(callback) {
   callback(); // Execute the parameter as a function
}

callTheCallback(someCallback);

let someCallbackReference = someCallback;

// Call the same function but indirectly via a variable
callTheCallback(someCallbackReference);
```

In the above example `someCallback` could indirectly origin from an other object.

You could even directly specify a function expression as a callback:

```
callTheCallback(function() {
   // ...
});
```

***With callbacks it's crucial to grasp the difference between passing a function call result and the function itself:***

```
callTheCallback(someCallback); // Callback function passed
callTheCallback(someCallback()); // Result of a function call passed
```

Note that it could be perfectly valid to pass the result of a function call if the return value itself is a function. This is also not uncommon in programming.

Callbacks are often used for [inversion of control (IoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) in general and [asynchronous programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous) specifically.

Examples for callback functions:

- Filtering arrays: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (IoC synchronous)
- Events: [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) (asynchronous)

In your case `fun()` is passed as third parameter callback to `add()`.

Now that you know how to use recursion and callbacks there are still semantic errors in your code...

## Semantical errors

In contrast to syntactical errors (wrong code grammar) semantical errors are errors with the meaning of the code.

### Interface of `add()`

Analyze your function [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/API):

```
function add(a, b, callback) {
  return /* some value - callback() call removed for simplicity */;
}
```

`add()` accepts *three parameters* and *returns a value*. The third parameter is named "callback" and thus shall be a function.

Your call of `add()` looks sensible although you don't use the returned value (which is not necessarily an error).

```
add(1, object.firsNum, fun);
```

### Implementation of `add()`

Since the parameters of `add()` are not documented, it is ambiguous what your intention was.

The name along with the fact that there are two parameters, `a` and `b`, leads one to the assumption that the two values shall be added. And you very well do this:

```
return callback(a + b);
```

But! what you've passed as callback function - which is `fun()` - expects different parameters, not a number. `fun()` expects an object.

Properly documented it would look like this:

```
/**
 * Recursively sum values until a maximum value is reached.
 * 
 * @param {Object} a object containing the sum, the increment and the max value
 * @param {Number} a.firsNum start value
 * @param {Number} a.maxNum the maxium value up to which to add "firsNum" to "sum"
 * @param {Number} a.sum the summed value, shall be 0 initially
 * @returns {undefined} nothing is returned
 */
function fun(a) {
  // ...
}
```

The above comment style is called JsDoc: https://jsdoc.app

Note to use proper names for functions, variables and parameters. Proper names help documenting the code whithout writing explicit documentation comments.

## Fixing the error

With the limited knowledge on what your actually wanted to achive one can only speculate. I assume `add()`, although it's name and parameters looks sensible, is implemented wrong. Your issue could be solved by calling the callback (`fun()`) correctly:

```
function add(obj, callback) {
  return callback(obj);
}
```

And:

```
add(object, fun);
```

Since we require the object `add()` now expects it as a single parameter.

Well that does not make a lot sense anymore now. `fun()` could be called directly from within `init()` and not via a callback reference and `add()` has as a confusing name.

***I won't further speculate what your intention was and how to implement alternative solutions to the problem.***

## What you've learned

- About [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)
- How recursion works
- Functions can be passed as parameters and be assigned to variables or properties
- Reading code
- The benefits of documenting code and properly naming functions and variables

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write all of this

Answer (score 0):

Just commented out the recursive code

```
function init() {
            let object = {
                firsNum: 1,
                sum: 0,
            };
            add(1, object.firsNum, fun);
            console.log(object.sum);
        }

        function fun(a) {
            a.firstNum++;
            a.sum += a.firsNum;
            //fun(a);
        }

        function add(a, b, callback) {
            return callback(a + b);
        }
        init();
```

Comment: I have output: 0. I want to pass add() method three arguments, and finally i want sum=3.

Answer (score 0):

## Your code

```
function init() {
  let object = {
    firsNum: 1,
    sum: 0,
  };
  add(1, object.firsNum, fun);
  console.log(object.sum);
}

function fun(a) {
  a.firstNum++;
  a.sum += a.firsNum;
  fun(a);
}

function add(a, b, callback) {
  return callback(a + b);
}
init();
```

## init

Defines an object with attributes of `firsNum` and `sum`, then calls `add`, passing 1, 1 and `fun`.

## fun

Receives a parameter. Increments `firstNum` of the parameter and adds it to `sum`. **Then it calls itself**.

## add

Gets three parameters: `a`, `b` and `callback`. Calls `callback` and passes `a + b` to it.

## The flow

`init` is called, then it calls `add` and passes 1 to `a`, 1 to `b` and `fun` to `callback`. As a result, add calls `callback`, which is `fun` and since both `a` and `b` are 1, `a + b` = 2 is passed to `fun`. `fun` increments `a.firstNum`, which seems to be a bug, since `a` is a number, then some other strange value is added to `sum`. Just remove `fun(a);` inside fun to get rid of recursion, but that's not the only bug in your code. Also, make sure that there is a `return` statement inside `fun`.